# datetimepicker restrain minHour and maxHour based on day selected

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Trying to restrict timepicker minHour and maxHour based on day of week of date selected. For example: selecting Tues. should limit option range to between 9am and 5pm but Wed should limit it to hours between 11am and 7pm. Stuck on how to pass minH and maxH back to the timepicker. As it stands, the code below closes upon selecting the date so user can't select time. I'm using bootstrap 4.3.1, jquery 3.4.1, jquery-ui 1.12.1, jquery-ui-timepicker-addon 1.6.3,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 7,
    stepMinute: 15,
    onSelect: function(selectedDateTime) {
        let findDayOfWeek = new Date(selectedDateTime);
        let foundDayOfWeek = findDayOfWeek.getDay();
        let minH;
        let maxH;
        //console.log(foundDayOfWeek);
        if (foundDayOfWeek = 2) {
            minH = '09:00';
            maxH = '17:00'
        }
        if (foundDayOfWeek = 3) {
            minH = '11:00';
            maxH = '19:00'
        }
        if (foundDayOfWeek = 4) {
            minH = '11:00';
            maxH = '17:00'
        }
        if (foundDayOfWeek = 5) {
            minH = '11:00';
            maxH = '17:00'
        }
        if (foundDayOfWeek = 6) {
            minH = '10:00';
            maxH = '15:00'
        }
        $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker('option', 'minHour', minH);
        $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker('option', 'maxHour', maxH);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found basis for a serviceable solution in this post: [Update the jquery timepicker addon from a date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927251/update-the-jquery-timepicker-addon-from-a-date-picker)
And my updated code is below. I hope it helps someone. A couple of notes: When I included a date Format, datepicker would select the previous date (for example, click on a Tues, and it returned Mon.) so I omitted the date format and the picker works. I also needed two separate fields - one for datepicker and one for timepicker -I could not accomplish this with a single datetimepicker (as in the examples using an alt field).

```
 $(function(){

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: closedDay,
    minDate: 7,
    stepMinute: 15,
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false },
    onSelect: function (dateText, instance) {
        let testDate = new Date(dateText);
        testDate = testDate.getDay();
        if(testDate) {
          if(testDate==2) {
            $("#timepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker");
            $("#timepicker").timepicker({
                hourMin: 9,
                hourMax: 16,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                stepMinute: 15,
                timeOnly: true
            });
          } else if(testDate==3){
            $("#timepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker");
            $("#timepicker").timepicker({
                hourMin: 11,
                hourMax: 18,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                stepMinute: 15,
                timeOnly: true
            });
          } else if(testDate==4 || testDate==5){
            $("#timepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker");
            $("#timepicker").timepicker({
                hourMin: 11,
                hourMax: 16,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                stepMinute: 15,
                timeOnly: true
            });
          } else {
            $("#timepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker");
            $("#timepicker").timepicker({
                hourMin: 10,
                hourMax: 14,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                stepMinute: 15,
                timeOnly: true
            });
          }
        }

    }
  });

  function closedDay(date) {
    let day = date.getDay();
    if(day == 0 || day == 1) {
      return [false];
    } else {
      return [true];
    }
  }

 });
```